# Telerik MVC Splitter jumping around

Tags: jquery, telerik, telerik-mvc, splitter

I'm trying to use the Telerik MVC Splitter. Completely loaded it looks very nice, but while loading the contained components are placed under each other making the layout completely messed up. Is there any simple solution?

Or are there any good jQuery-splitter you could recommend? I actually like it better to have complete control of my layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for Telerik and did the development on the Splitter.*

### Solutions

- **Asynchroniously load the splitter content** - You can speed up the page loading by using the [LoadContentForm method](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/m_telerik_web_mvc_ui_fluent_splitterpanebuilder_loadcontentfrom_2.html) when building the panes. The UI will feel much more responsive, as you can [see on the demo site](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc-beta/splitter/ajaxloading).
- **Provide styles for the panes through their HtmlAttributes** - you can style each of the panes using CSS `float`s, so that the layout makes sense in your scenario. This is too custom to achieve out-of-the-box.

### Why is it so hard?

In order to solve this problem, we had to render the layout from the server. This, however, is rather impossible to do when you don't know the size of the splitter (which is usually 100% of the container), *unless* we use HTML `<table>`s for layout (which brings more problems to the table, rather than fixing them). Therefore, we opted out of it and decided to size it on the client. We are researching more options to make the process easier ([CSS3 flexbox module](http://www.the-haystack.com/2010/01/23/css3-flexbox-part-1/)), but for a cross-browser solution, use the above methods.